# Update trunk with tag created with Maven Release plugin

Tags: git, maven

I have a working Maven release process but I still need to do some manual tasks.

Here's a summary of the process:

1. release:prepare
2. release:perform

I run the above in the development branch. This of course creates a tag and then updates the branch with the next development version. In my case I would like it also to update trunk. I like to have trunk with the code of the latest release, but if I do a merge/pull it'll copy the new development version not the last release.

Is there a way to get in there or doing it manually is the only way?

Comment: fairly sure you will have to do this manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the tag name you can simply:

```
git push origin release-x.y.z:refs/heads/master
```

Or if you know that the latest release is the previous commit, then:

```
git push origin HEAD~1:refs/heads/master
```

You can probably configure this via [Maven SCM Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkin-mojo.html). But if there is a possibility that master was updated, then this would fail and you'd have to merge manually.

PS: Heh, there are still people who use Maven Release Plugin :)

Comment: I guess that would work, but I was asking about something to do as part of the Maven release.

Comment: You can probably use SCM plugin for this (updated the answer). As for the better options - not using release plugin would be one :) It's just too complicated and releases don't happen so often anyway. If you have Continuous Delivery and releases are frequent, then the whole idea of generating "nice" release version is not very practical and thus you wouldn't use Release Plugin anyway. I'd start with this book if you're interested https://martinfowler.com/books/continuousDelivery.html Written very poorly, but has main ideas listed.